# Store everything after second `/`

Tags: powershell

I have this string in a Powershell Variable:

```
$buildParametersSourceBranch = refs/heads/pb/31333-test-branch/name
```

When I run `$buildParametersSourceBranch.split('/')[2]`

The result is `pb`. I assumed the split would show everything after the second `/` but it seems to only show the value between the second `/` and third `/`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String.Split()` doesn't "know" that you're only interested in a particular subset of the result and only want the string split in 2 places.

Use the `-split` operator and specify a max number of resulting substrings:

```
$rest = ($buildParametersSourceBranch -split '/',3)[2]
# or
$null,$null,$rest = $buildParametersSourceBranch -split '/',3
```

Comment: It even  works with the `.split()`-method: `$buildParametersSourceBranch.Split('/',3)[2]`

Comment: @T-Me: What mathias tried to explain is `.split()` is a method on a string. It comes in automatically because PowerShell is built on .NET and takes all the features of .NET types. Whereas, `-split` is a PowerShell operator, it's a shortcut to `[regex]::Split()`. It can split more things than strings (by forcibly casting them to string) . In this case, the used case remains same , so working for both.

Comment: Another alternative: Instead of assignments to the `$null` variable you can also use `Select-Object`. I feel it improves readability: `$buildParametersSourceBranch -split '/',3 | Select-Object -Last 1`